# Python matplotlib / Seaborn stripplot with connection between points

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I'm using Python 3 and Seaborn to make categorical stripplots (see code and image below).

Each stripplot has 2 data points (one for each gender).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns


df = [["city2", "f", 300],
    ["city2", "m", 39],
    ["city1", "f", 95],
    ["city1", "m", 53]]

df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns = ["city", "gender", "variable"])

sns.stripplot(data=df,x='city',hue='gender',y='variable', size=10, linewidth=1)
```

I get the following output [image]

However, I would like to have a line segment connecting the male and female points. I would like the figure to look like this (see pic below). However, I manually drew those red lines and I'm wondering if there is a simple way to do it w/ Seaborn or matplotlib. Thank you!
[image]

Comment: You could always make your own wrapper to draw the lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a list of f-m pairs using `pandas.dataframe.groupby` and then plot the segments between pairs:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import collections  as mc
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns


df = [["city2", "f", 300],
      ["city2", "m", 39],
      ["city1", "f", 95],
      ["city1", "m", 53],
      ["city4", "f", 200],
      ["city3", "f", 100],
      ["city4", "m", 236],
      ["city3", "m", 20],]


df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns = ["city", "gender", "variable"])


ax = sns.stripplot(data=df,x='city',hue='gender',y='variable', size=10, linewidth=1)

lines = ([[x, n] for n in group] for x, (_, group) in enumerate(df.groupby(['city'], sort = False)['variable']))
lc = mc.LineCollection(lines, colors='red', linewidths=2)    
ax.add_collection(lc)

sns.plt.show()
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: `AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'add_collections'.` My code is the same as yours..

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a small thing to this to save someone time in the future. This solution worked for me, but you'll notice that the vertical lines don't align perfectly with the circle markers in some instances. As far as I can tell, the reason for this has to do with figsize and dpi stuff (not xtick ranges). If you compare a saved .png version of your figure with the version that is displayed/generated in your GUI (Spyder in my case), you see that they're different and that the .png file has correctly aligned markers and lines.